# Matching structure with regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

Is it possible to match a string like `ABA BCB CDC DED ...` using a regex? If so, how? Note the repeating structure but not the exact same letters.

Answer (score 0):

Use the regexp `(?:(\w)(\w)\1 )+`. The non capturing group describes the pattern you want and the + just says you want one or more of that pattern repeated. Not though that the string must end in a space for it to match.

Comment: That's great, but I don't want to match `ABA BCB BCB `.